# Automatic zeroes in an Excel column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365

I'm new to Excel and I was wondering what could be done about this issue.

What I did:

1. Created a table for a simple list.
2. Keyed in Cost and Quantity
3. =D5*E5 for the first item's total

The subsequent values for the Total column shows zeroes, which I don't want.

I want a list wherein the **Total** column is only populated after its corresponding row for **Cost** and **Quantity** is keyed in.

Secondly, I'd also like to know how to specify a dynamic range for the calculating **Grand Total** (since the size of list is variable) on a different cell.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `=IF(AND(D5<>"",E5<>""),D5*E5,"")` for your first question (depending on your regional settings you may need to use `;` instead of `,`). Regarding your second question, just google for "excel dynamic range", you'll find plenty of great tutorials.

Comment: And you might have to localize function names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `IF` statement for your first question:

```
=IF(AND(D5<>"",E5<>""),D5*E5,"")
```

& to create a dynamic range you can use `OFFSET`.

Press `Ctrl` + `F3`and click `New`.

Then enter the below formula in the refers to box :

Change Sheet1, to that of the sheet where your Grand Total Is,

Change $A$1, to the Cell where the header Grand Total is.

& Change $A:$A to the column which has the Grand Total.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,1)
```

Give the range a name, then you can use the below to sum it:

```
=SUM(example)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**My solution has a  different approach:**

*You can try this formula for the first part of the question to avoid,  "subsequent values for the Total column shows zeros".*

```
=IF(NOT(OR(D5="",E5="",D5=0,E5=0)),(D5*E5),"Cell Blank/Zero")
```

**How it works:**

- Formula will check both `D5` & `E5`, whether they are neither blank
  nor contains Zero and if not then only multiple `D5` with `E5`.

*Below is the Dynamic formula to Calculate the Grand Total.*

```
=SUM(Sheet1!A1:INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(9.999999E+307,Sheet1!A:A)))
```

**How it works:**

`MATCH(9.999999E+307,Sheet1!A:A)`

- Returns total number of values in entire column A of Sheet 1, which changes
  according to the number of entries been updated and makes the formula Dynamic 
  to SUM values .

**N.B.**

*Adjust Cell references & Sheet Name in formula as needed.*